# Trying to pass a parameter but getting a "context" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass this from my controller into my view (`@ViewBag.Chapter7Total`):

```
ViewBag.Chapter7Total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData, Chapter7);
```

But am getting a "doesn't exist in the current context error" in VS.

Basically, I am trying to pass in a second parameter which determines which pricing structure to use between 2. Chapter7 or Chapter13, with the selection determining the second parameter to perform calculations with.

Here are my methods:

```
class Chapter
{
    public decimal PaymentPlan { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public decimal decPaymentPlan(QuoteData quoteData, Chapter chapter)
{
    if (quoteData.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlanRadioButton 
        == StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.No)
        return PriceQuote.priceNoPaymentPlan;
    else
        return chapter.PaymentPlan;
}

public decimal Calculate(QuoteData quoteData, Chapter chapter)
{
    decimal total = chapter.Price;
    total += this.decPaymentPlan(quoteData, chapter);

    return total;
}

static Chapter Chapter7 = new Chapter() { Price = 799.00m, PaymentPlan = 100.00m };
```

Finally, this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult EMailQuote()
{
    Calculations calc = new Calculations();
    Chapter chap = new Chapter();

    QuoteData quoteData = new QuoteData
    {
        StepFilingInformation = new Models.StepFilingInformation
        {
            //just moking user input here temporarily to test out the UI
            PaymentPlanRadioButton = Models.StepFilingInformation.PaymentPlan.Yes,
        }
     };

     var total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData);
     ViewBag.Chapter7Total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData, Chapter7);
     return View(quoteData);
}
```

I'm not sure what to do to pass Chapter7. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 1:**

This is my ViewModel (`QuoteData`):

```
public class QuoteData
{
    public PriceQuote priceQuote;
    public Calculations calculations;
    public StepFilingInformation stepFilingInformation { get; set; }
    public QuoteData()
    {
        PriceQuote = new PriceQuote();
        Calculations = new Calculations();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ViewBag instead of adding the value to a ViewModel with a property defined? That is the preferred method to sending data to a View

Comment: Agreed, just that I am struggling to do just that and settled on ViewBag. Would you be able to share a sample? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out what you are doing here but I see that most importantly, you are sending `quoteData` to your View. I'm making a guess here but I figure `QuoteData` is a custom entity type of yours and not a `ViewModel`.

To start, I would create a `QuoteDataViewModel` in your models with all the properties of `QuoteData` that you need, including

```
public class QuoteDataViewModel {
   ... all of your quoteData properties here
   public Chapter Chapter7 { get; set; }
}
```

In your `EMailQuote` action, something similar to this

```
public ActionResult EMailQuote() {
    ...
    var model = new QuoteDataViewModel();
    var quoteData = new QuoteData();
    ... // map your quoteData to your model with Automapper or manually like
    ... // model.SomeProperty = quoteData.SomeProperty;
    ... // repeat for all properties
    model.Chapter7 = Chapter7;
    return View(model);
}
```

If you are posting this data back you would need your `Post` action to accept the new `QuoteDataViewModel`

```
public ActionResult EmailQuote(QuoteDataViewModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        ....//save data that was entered?
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Your view would then take a QuoteDateViewModel

```
@model QuoteDataViewModel
```

This is all just how I would do it personally, I don't quite understand what you have going on, for example, this line:

```
var total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData);
```

I don't see `total` ever being used after you create it.

Anyway, that's just a sample of how I'd do it, create a model specific to the view, include any and all properties I need, populate the model in the controller and send it to the view

### Update

Based on the OP comment that quoteData is a ViewModel, then just as above, adding the new property to hold the extra data is simple, by adding ...

```
public decimal QuoteTotal { get; set; }
public Chapter Chapter7 { get; set; }
```

...to the ViewModel

the controller populates

```
var total = calc.CalculatePrice(quoteData);
model.QuoteTotal = total;
model.Chapter7 = new Chapter();
model.Chapter7 = Chapter7;
```

In the View the values can be accessed like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.QuoteTotal)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Chapter7.PaymentPlan)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Chapter7.Price)
```

Comment: Sorry not more explicit, `QuoteData` is my ViewModel. Will update post to reflect that.

Comment: Ok cool, then you can just add a property to it to hold your Chapter instance

Comment: Like `public Chapter Chapter`?

Comment: Before trying to pass the second parameter of Chapter7/Chapter13, I was using total thusly: `ViewBag.CalculatePrice = total;` and just calling `@ViewBag.CalculatePrice` in the View. This is what I was focusing on getting right to try and pass that second parameter.